# Почему не создаётся .ini файл?

Tags: delphi, ini

Использую данный код для создания .ini файла в папке с проектом:

```
uses
  IniFiles

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Ini: TIniFile;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Ini := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+'config.ini');
  Ini.Free;
end;
```

но при запуске ничего не создаётся. В чём дело ?

Comment: а если туда чуточку чего то записать?

Comment: @KoVadim что дописать ?

Comment: записать внутрь ини файла какие-либо значения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С точки зрения программы пустой ini файл и отсутствующий эквивалентно. Поэтому, нет данных - нет смысла сохранять.